# How can apply style using withEvents in multiplesheets in maatwebsite 3.1?

Tags: excel, laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel

I have used laravel excel version 2.1 previously . In version 2.0 cell designing was pretty easy . So i started a new project in latest edition of laravel (6) and was shocked to know that we can't use laravel excel version 2.0 in this version of laravel . I installed latest version of laravel-excel 3.1 and sheet styling is totally different from the version larave-excel version 2.0 so i dig into documentation i found this custom styles using registerEvents for the multiple sheets but it didn't work.

Here is my Export class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Excel;
use App\Exports\ExportSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;


class ExcelExport implements WithMultipleSheets, WithEvents
{
    use Exportable;
    /**
    * @var Invoice $invoice
    */
    protected $excel_input;

    private $writerType = 'xlsx';

    public function __construct($excel_input)
    {
        $this->excel_input = $excel_input;
    }

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $data   = $this->excel_input;
        $sheets = [];

        foreach($data as $sheet_data) {
            $sheets[] =  new ExportSheet($sheet_data);
        }
        return $sheets;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        $normal_style = array('font' => array('name' => 'Times New Roman','size' => 15));

        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) use($normal_style) {
                $event->sheet->getStyle("A:Z")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $event->sheet->getStyle("A:Z")->applyFromArray($normal_style);
                $event->sheet->setAutoSize(true);
                $event->sheet->setScale('100');
                $event->sheet->setFitToHeight(false);
                $event->sheet->setFitToWidth(true);
                $event->sheet->setPageMargin(0.25);
            },
        ];
    }

}
```

Here is my ExportSheet file for generate multiple sheets.

````
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style;

class ExportSheet implements WithTitle, ShouldAutoSize, FromView, WithColumnFormatting
{
    private $sheet_data;


    public function __construct(array $sheet_data)
    {
        $this->sheet_data = $sheet_data;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        $data = $this->sheet_data;
        return $data['sheet_name'];
    }

    public function ShouldAutoSize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
        $info = $this->sheet_data;
        return view($info['template_name'])->with(['data'=>$info]);
    }
}```
````

Comment: I thought it's bug because of `$event->sheet` is for single sheet only.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. the `registerEvents` worked fine without `implements WithMultipleSheets`. But after `implements WithMultipleSheets`, it didn't work anymore.

Is there anyone give me some advices please?

Answer (score 0):

I found that moving the event register to the individual sheet class(es) worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).